# Linking a javascript pop-up function to a hyperlink-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I'm sort of new here, so if my question has already been answered, please don't jump down my throat; I have been searching for answers though.

Ok, so here's what I need to do:
On the website I'm busy with, there is an external css modified hyperlink tag, made to look like a button. Once clicked, it redirects the user to a sign-up page.
The html and css for the hyprelink element:

```css
.button_promo {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 3px solid #ef4923;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #787878;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Vag, helvetica, arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 21px;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="signup.html" class="button_promo">Sign up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I need to do is change the function of the element, so that when the user clicks on it, it brings up a pop-up instead. However, this is the pop-up function code I need to use:

```js
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.type = 'text/javascript';
  e.async = true;
  e.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://btn.createsend1.com/js/sb.min.js?v=3';
  e.className = 'createsend-script';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
})
();
```

```html
<div class="createsend-button" style="height:27px;display:inline-block;" data-listid="i/41/44A/73A/85038CAF46C6F93F">

</div>
```

The pop-up function code creates it's own button, but I don't want that. I need to link it to the Hyperlink tag, without changing the style of the link. So, I need the function to not create it's own button, but to carry out the actual motion of bringing up the desired pop-up once the link is clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use a modal window?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but a quick and dirty workaround, would be hiding the created button and triggering a click in your button to click the popup button.

I would not recommend doing that, but the script that is loaded is hard to understand (for me).

Something like that should work:

```js
document.querySelector('.botton_promo').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.createsend-button').click();
});
```

```css
.createsend-button {
  display: none;
}
```

And I would recommend giving your button an ID

Answer (score 0):

Just change your link/button appropriately. You can delete that js function. You don't have to use that.

```
<a href="signup.html" class="button_promo">Sign up</a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button_promo" onclick="window.open("http://www.somelink.com", "_blank", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=400,height=400")">Sign up</a>
```